# Using group by and order by together

Tags: sql, oracle

Im having trouble including the order by function with the group by function.

I want to find out the student with the highest attendance rate in each of the 3 years.

Tables:

Student

```
studentPIN | fName | lName | StudyYear 

    1          x       x         1
    2          x       x         2
    3          x       x         3
    4          x       x         2
```

AttendanceLog 
N.B status refers to if they attended the class or not.

```
ClassID | StudentPin | Status 
   12          1         NO
   23          2         YES
   34          3         YES
```

Currently I have been able to count the number of times each student has attended a class.

This is currently what I am working with:

```
Select student.fname, student.lname, STUDENT.STUDYYEAR,
SUM(CASE ATTENDANCELOG.STATUS WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Attended 
from student 
Join ATTENDANCELOG on student.studentpin=ATTENDANCELOG.studentpin
GROUP BY STUDENT.STUDYYEAR, STUDENT.FNAME, STUDENT.LNAME
```

I am just stuck on how to order the results from highest attendance to lowest and then select the top one for each of the 3 years.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of the Oracle DB server are you working with?

Comment: @Hilarion SQL Developer 18.1.0

Comment: SQL Developer is a client application you are using to access the DB server, it's not the DB server itself. You could try executing one of those queries, to obtain the version numbers of your DB server: `SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION` or `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select fname, lname, studyyear, attended
from (select s.fname, s.lname, s.STUDYYEAR,
             SUM(CASE al.STATUS WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Attended,
             row_number() over (partition by s.studyyear
                                order by SUM(CASE al.STATUS WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from student s Join
           ATTENDANCELOG al
           on s.studentpin = al.studentpin
      group by s.STUDYYEAR, s.FNAME, s.LNAME
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Tried this and it just prompts that there are invalid identifiers when all wording is correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select student.fname, student.lname, STUDENT.STUDYYEAR,
SUM(CASE ATTENDANCELOG.STATUS WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Attended 
from student 
Join ATTENDANCELOG on student.studentpin=ATTENDANCELOG.studentpin
GROUP BY STUDENT.STUDYYEAR, STUDENT.FNAME, STUDENT.LNAME
ORDER BY 4 desc;
```